# How do I use a custom trained multilingual text classifier model as they do in WWDC23?

Tags: swift, nlp

```
guard let embedding = NLContextualEmbedding(language: .english) else{return}
let dimension = embedding.dimension
print(dimension)
```

So this is done in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10042/ and this may be a stupid question and I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something but what exactly is this doing? If I just trained my own model in Create ML and want to use that to classify some text how would I go about doing that if I've added it to my Xcode project?

Comment: Okay I have already actually figured out how to get my custom text classification model but could maybe someone still explain what the code I included is doing? Like still don't fully understand it.